# How to use while loop on a meshgrid in matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I am taking a course on Coursera where I am stuck on a project for a while now and I am frustrated as hell. Please and help would be appreciated. The question is as follows:

Question: Determine a fractal that arises from using Newton’s method to compute the fixed-point solutions of the Lorenz equations. Use the parameter values r = 28, σ = 10 and β = 8/3. Initial values (x0, z0) are taken on a grid in the x-z plane with always y0 = 3√2. For assessment purposes, the computational grid and the graphics code will be given in the Learner Template. To pass the assessment, every pixel in your figure needs to be colored correctly. (Hint: Some grid points may require as many as 33 Newton iterations to converge while others may require as few as three. Unfortunately, if you uniformly use 33 Newton iterations at every grid point, the Matlab Grader may time out. You can accelerate your code by using a while loop instead of a for loop.)

The template is given as follow:

```
r=28; sigma=10; beta=8/3;
x1=0; y1=0; z1=0;
x2=sqrt(beta*(r-1)); y2=sqrt(beta*(r-1)); z2=r-1;
x3=-sqrt(beta*(r-1)); y3=-sqrt(beta*(r-1)); z3=r-1;
nx=500; ny=500;
xmin=-40; xmax=40; ymin=-40; ymax=40;
x_grid=linspace(xmin,xmax,nx); y_grid=linspace(ymin,ymax,ny);
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x_grid,y_grid);


% Write Newton's method using every gridpoint as the initial condition
% Perform enough iterations at each gridpoint to converge to the correct root
% Save the x-values of the converged roots in the matrix X
% To pass the assessment, every pixel in the figure must be correctly colored
%!!!!!!!!! Set initial value y=3*sqrt(2) for all values (x,y) on the grid !!!!!!!!!!


eps=0.001;
X1 = abs(X-x1) < eps; X2 = abs(X-x2) < eps; X3 = abs(X-x3) < eps;
X4 = ~(X1+X2+X3);
figure;
map = [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 0 0 0]; colormap(map); %[red;green;blue;black]
X=(X1+2*X2+3*X3+4*X4);
image([xmin xmax], [ymin ymax], X); set(gca,'YDir','normal');
xlabel('$x$', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize',14);
ylabel('$y$', 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize',14);
title('Fractal from the Lorenz Equations', 'Interpreter', 'latex','FontSize', 16)
```

The problem for me is that I have no idea how to use while loop in a way that it terminates for some points on the meshgrid and continue for others. I am fairly new to MATLAB and I've seen that you can perform an operation (e.g., Newton's method) on meshgrid at once using for loop but not for the while-loop. I've tried couple different codes:

Edit: I managed to get progress with the following code.

```
Y = 3*sqrt(2);
Z1 = Z(:,1);
X1 = X(1,:);

for j = 1:nx
    x1 = X1(j);
    for k = 1:nz
        error = Inf;
        x = x1;
        y = 3*sqrt(2);
        z = Z1(k);
        while error > 0.0001
            J=    [-10, 10, 0; 28 - z, -1, -x; y, x, -8/3];
            rhs =  - [10*(y-x); x*(28-z)-y; x*y- (8/3)*z];
            delta_xyz=J\rhs;
            x = x + delta_xyz(1);
            y = y + delta_xyz(2);
            z = z + delta_xyz(3);
            error=abs(delta_xyz(1));
                         
        end
            X(501-k,j) = x;
    end
end
```

But now I have a different problem. On the graph that is generated, I don't see any red pixels. (only green, blue and black). red pixels are supposed to be for values of x that are closed to 0. Intuitively, the region surrounding the origin should converge to 0, but I do not know why it doesn't. To check this I wrote

```
abs(X(200:300,200:300)) < 1.e-03
```

in the MATLAB command line and I see many 1's, indicating that the values are close to zero for many points near the origin, but why wouldn't they exhibit red colors??? Can someone point out a problem(s) with the code?
Edit: it turns out I used x1 variable that was predefined which messed up the result, I've gotten so far, but I still don't get the right answer. But anyway, thanks for all the help!

I have no idea and I spent so much time that I don't have the energy to go on. Can someone give me any good insight? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you intend `J` to look like? You need it to be a 3x3 matrix, how do you think your larger `X`, `Y` and `Z` matrices could fit in there?

Comment: To speed up your first attempt, did you try making the tolerance larger? You might not need such small values to converge. You need to initialize `error` before entering the while loop, and your `for` loops don’t actually loop, they assess the first sample only. If the code times out, you have an error in the method itself.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I don't know what J is supposed to look like, to be honest. In the previous exercise, we could perform Z = Z - f(Z)/f'(Z), f(z) = z^4 -1 and Z was a meshgrid on complex plane. So I just thought the Jacobian J would work the same way.

Comment: You need to do `for i = 1:size(X,2)` and `for j = 1:size(X,1)`. You are iterating over the array `1`, which has only one element, and therefore the loop runs only once. I highly recommend that you read some [MATLAB tutorials](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html), rather than treating lines of code as "magic incantations" that you copy-paste without understanding. Getting the MATLAB basics right will make all of your exercises so much easier.

Comment: Yes. I was trying one case at a time to see what was wrong and I forgot to change it back to an actual loop. I am trying to get the basics of MATLAB but that would take awhile so decided to ask online to see what I was missing. Thanks for the response.

Comment: The `Max` in `error=max(abs(delta_xyz(1));` doesn’t do anything, its input is a single value. I also just now noticed that it misses a closing parenthesis. Just do `error=abs(delta_xyz(1));`

Comment: Apart from controlling if the step update `max(abs(delta_xyz))` becoming small enough, you also need to bail out if the update becomes large, perhaps larger than 100, or better, if the point itself moves far away from the relevant cube of radius 50. Newton for polynomials is relatively stable, as it generally moves towards the root cluster from any point in the complex plane. General multidimensional Newton does not have this property. Apart from a small set around the roots, there is no guarantee of convergence or even that the sequence of Newton iterates stays bounded.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. I understand what you mean, but it seems that the professor made sure they all converge in this region, as I had no issue. Could you check the issue I have with red pixels and why my graph doesn't have any red pixels? Thanks a lot.